# port binding debugging in specman

Tags: specman

I work with quite a big environment, which I am not familiar with most of it. There is now a DUT error reported by a checker. The problem is - the checker gets data items via ports. Is there an e method that can show which monitors are connected to the checker (so that I can see which monitor drove the bad data)? Also - how can I tell where in the code the checker was connected to the monitors?

Comment: `show ports -full` should help.

Comment: `print_stack_trace()` is very very useful in large environments.

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to debug external and internal port bindings:

1) You can use the get_inbound_set() on a specific port to get all the ports it is bound to.

2) Trace commands:

- to debug procedural connections:(do_bind() or connect()) - use “trace bind”.
- for static generation binding (keep bind()) - use “trace gen”.

3) we recommend using the procedural approach : connect() & do_bind() , as it simplifies the debugging , and does not burden the generator.

just a side note, you can also use:

- "trace esi" : use this trace only up until the run phase , to see the full attribute list that was given to every port in your environment
- "show ports" : show you information about a specific port or all ports in your environment , read the doc to see what kind of information can be seen. it is recommended to use this command after all of the port bindings are done.